# How would you check an array for correctness?

Tags: c, arrays, error-checking

I have an array of prime numbers. The length of this array is 1,000,000. This means that my last element primes[999999] should have the 1 millionth prime, and actually it should have the 1,000,001th prime since I left 2 out of the beginning.

When I run my program and have it spit out the last element of the array it spits out the 999,999th prime number. I am in the process of learning C and this is a little homework project for a math class I am taking. I have no idea where to even start in my troubleshooting of this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Sorry, for some reason I thought it might be an easy answer. I posted the code below. I have printed out the array of primes under option 1 and all the primes are correct and the result is correct. Any other option and I get an erroneous output.

```
void createArray( int, unsigned long long * );
unsigned long long root(unsigned long long);
void print( unsigned long long *, int );

int main(void){

    unsigned long long *prime = (unsigned long long *)calloc(SIZE6, 
                                    sizeof(unsigned long long));
    unsigned long long *ptrEmpty = &prime[15];
    unsigned long long i;
    unsigned long long j;
    long int sizeComp;
    int flag = 0;
    unsigned long option = 0;
    int length = 0;

    system( "clear" );

    do{ 
        flag = 0;
        option = -1;

        printf( "Welcome to the prime number finder program. Below are a list "
            "of prime numbers\nyou can find as well as their average runni"
            "ng time on the Loki system of UNO.\n\nOption 1: Return the 10"
            "0th prime number. ( Running time: .006s )\nOption 2: Return t"
            "he 1000th prime number. ( Running time: .008s )\nOption 3: Re"
            "turn the 10000th prime number. ( Running time: .089s )\nOptio"
            "n 4: Return the 100000th prime number. ( Running time: 2.188s"
            " )\nOption 5: Return the 1000000th prime number. ( Running ti"
            "me: 57.156s )\nOption 6: Return the 10000000th prime number. "
            "( **CAUTION!** Running time: 35m51.3s )\n\nEnter the number o"
            "f the option you would like the program to\nperform (Enter 0 "
            "to exit):  " );

        scanf( "%lu", &option );

        switch( option ){

            case 0:
                flag = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                createArray( SIZE1, prime );
                ptrEmpty = &prime[15];
                length = SIZE1;
                break;
            case 2:
                createArray( SIZE2, prime );
                ptrEmpty = &prime[15];
                length = SIZE2;
                break;
            case 3:
                createArray( SIZE3, prime );
                ptrEmpty = &prime[15];
                length = SIZE3;
                break;
            case 4:
                createArray( SIZE4, prime );
                ptrEmpty = &prime[15];
                length = SIZE4;
                break;
            case 5:
                createArray( SIZE5, prime );
                ptrEmpty = &prime[15];
                length = SIZE5;
                break;
            case 6:
                createArray( SIZE6, prime );
                ptrEmpty = &prime[15];
                length = SIZE6;
                break;
            default:
                printf( "Please enter one of the available options ( 1 - 7 ) "
                "or 0 to exit:  " );
            flag= 1;
            break;
        }

        if( flag != 1 ){
            for( i = START, sizeComp = 15; sizeComp <= length; i += 2 ){

                flag = 0;
                for( j = 0; prime[j] < root( i ); j++ ){

                    if( ( i % prime[j] ) == 0 ){
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if( flag == 0 ){
                    *ptrEmpty = i;
                    ++sizeComp;
                    ptrEmpty++;
                }
            }

            printf( "\nThe %dth prime number is %llu.\n\n", length, 
                    prime[ length - 2 ]);

//            print( prime, length );
            printf( "****************************************"
                    "****************************************\n\n" );

    }

    }while( option != 0 );

    free( prime );

    return 0;
}

void print( unsigned long long *prime, int length ){

    int i;
    printf( "\n%4d", 2 );
    for( i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf( "%4llu ", prime[i] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}

void createArray( int length, unsigned long long *prime ){

    unsigned long long *pHolder = NULL;

    pHolder = (unsigned long long *)realloc( prime, length * 
                                        sizeof( unsigned long long ) );

    if(pHolder != NULL){
        prime = pHolder;
    }else{
        free( prime );
        printf( "Error reallocating memory.\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    prime[0] = 3;
    prime[1] = 5;
    prime[2] = 7;
    prime[3] = 11;
    prime[4] = 13;
    prime[5] = 17;
    prime[6] = 19;
    prime[7] = 23;
    prime[8] = 29;
    prime[9] = 31;
    prime[10] = 37;
    prime[11] = 41;
    prime[12] = 43;
    prime[13] = 47;
    prime[14] = 53;
}

unsigned long long root(unsigned long long a) {

    unsigned long long rem = 0;
    unsigned long long root = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        root <<= 1;
        rem <<= 2;
        rem += a >> 30;
        a <<= 2;

        if (root < rem) {
            root++;
            rem -= root;
            root++;
        }
    }

    return (root >> 1);
}
```

Edit:
SIZE1 = 100, SIZE2 = 1000, SIZE3 = 10000, SIZE4 = 100000, SIZE5 = 1000000, SIZE6 = 10000000

Comment: How about showing some code?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: If you post your code, someone will likely point out your bug.  If you want to figure it out by yourself, you could try using `printf` to output debug info while your program is running.  I'd start by printing out the start of the array to check you really are ignoring the first 2 primes.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I added the code to my post above along with some additional info.

Comment: `createArray` reallocates `prime` and assigns the resulting address to the identifier `prime`. At that point, `prime` refers to the local parameter of the function `createArray`. Assigning to it does not change the pointer in the main program. `createArray` must return the new pointer so the main program can update `prime`, or `createArray` must be passed a pointer to the pointer `prime` so that it can change the pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil how would i fix it then? When i call createArray pass it &(prime) and then the prototype would say; createArray( unsigned long long **prime, int length)? Then the assignment would look like this; *prime = pHolder?

Comment: @user1362058: Yes, that is a common way to deal with the problem. Also, all uses of `prime` in the `createArray` function would be changed to `(*prime)`. There may be other issues in your program; that is just one I noticed.

Answer (score 3):

You could go about debugging this, by changing your array size to 5 and only looking at the first 5 primes, print out all 5 of them, and see if it's actually 2 3 5 7 11 (or in your case 3 5 7 11 13) or if you have some error there.

Your error will probably exist there and you can then correct it for the much smaller case and it should work for the larger case.

Comment: what's weird is that the array is perfectly fine with the size set to 100. Anything larger and the output is not correct. I don't have the patience to sift through the 1000 numbers that are output and check to make sure they each match up. Maybe someone can find the error in my code now that I have updated my original post with the code I am currently working with.

Comment: Binary search for the number you are looking for (what seems to be an incorrect prime), change Size2 to 500, then 750 if its okay, then 875 if it's okay and continue on like that and you should be able to find the exact # that is screwing up your program pretty easily.  And at that point there will probably be something specific about that number that makes sense for why it doesn't work.